# PHP How to echo JSON object

Tags: php, json, printing, echo, explode

I tried several times to echo a JSON object, with explode() function, but I did not succeed. I think I'm using a wrong method, but I can not find another way to do it.

I want to echo a JSON like:

```
{
    "Title_Book": "Harry Potter",
    "Volume": [
        {
            "Name": "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone",
            "Actor": [
                {
                    "Actor": "Actor0"
                },
                {
                    "Actor": "Actor1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Name": "Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets",
            "Actor": [
                {
                    "Actor": "Actor0"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
 "Title_Book" : Another Book
  ... 
}
```

As:

> ```
> Title : Book
> Volume[0][0] : Name of the book : Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone
> Volume[0][1] : Actor 1
> Volume[0][2] : Actor 1 
> Volume[1][0] : Name of the book : Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets
> Volume[1][1] : Actor 0 
>
> Title1 ...
> ```

Comment: Looks like you have to remove keys on the Volume array. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

use [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) with second parameter set to true.

example code:

```
$booksArray = json_decode($libraryJsonString,true);

foreach ($booksArray as $books) {

    print_r($books);

}
```

instead of `print_r($booksArray);` you may put another foreach loop to iterate over every element of the array. to see how the array looks stright after decoding it use:

```
$booksArray = json_decode($libraryJsonString,true);
print_r($booksArray);
```